# No audio after El Capitan update - Python OS-X

Tags: python, macos, audio, pygame

I'm planning on displaying an old university project during a job interview. It is essentially a Python based 'drum machine'.

The project is over a year old, and I am on OSX. Updating to El Capitan has completely broken port audio and therefore I have no way of playing audio - a severe problem for an audio based project.

```
Code is linked below
```

[Here's the code](https://ideone.com/dZQlGU)

Does anyone know of any changes in El Capitan that would have affected outputting audio?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the sound part of pygame, or what your actual problem is, but I can try a guess. SDL is incompatible with newer mac versions, for sure El Capitan. I had to get a virtual machine to code pygame on linux because my mac side had buggy pictures. This issue could extend to sound, but I'm not sure if incompatibility is the issue.

Comment: Yes this is a known problem for newer versions of osx and pygame. Best bet, run it on a virtual machine just for the interview or boot into linux from a usb or something.